# How auto scroll to position of a focusable JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextfield, autoscroll

I'm using a `JScrollPane` container which has a `JPanel` in it.
Inside the JPanel there are many labels and `JTextFields`. Now the last JTextField doesn't show at the start and **I want to get to it using the TAB button** and also have the **vertical scroller scroll to it.**

I tried

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textField.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

and also:

```
scrollRectToVisible( textField.getBounds() );
```

'

didn't work :(

this is the code:

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InsertNewOrderWindow frame = new InsertNewOrderWindow();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public InsertNewOrderWindow() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 903, 1001);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel , JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS , JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 577));
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    ...... // gridBag stuff

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {


            DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textField.getCaret();
            caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);


        }
    });

    ... // gridBag stuff
    panel.add(textField, gbc_textField_19);
    ...

} //InsertNewOrderWindow() method
```

how can I auto scroll to the focusable jtextfield?

Answer (score 3):

> how can I auto scroll to the focusable jtextfield?

Check out [Scrolling a Form](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/scrolling-a-form/) for a simple solution.

The class uses the `KeyboardFocusManager` to listen for focus changes and will then make sure the component that has focus is displayed in the viewport of the scroll pane.